# Glib Error on kfce-panel

Tags: xfce, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xfce-panel

I got this error when using the default settings of the xfce4 panel
someone help me :D

```
icezilla@DESKTOP-9C2LV7B:~/Desktop$ xfce4-panel
**
GLib:ERROR:../../../../glib/gtimezone.c:498:init_zone_from_iana_info: assertion failed: (trans.info_index < gtz->t_info->len)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Ubuntu 18.04 bash on Windows 10 with X410

```
(xfce4-panel:9123): xfce4-panel-CRITICAL **: 21:37:48.570: panel-application.c:1250 (panel_application_save): expression 'XFCONF_IS_CHANNEL (channel)' failed.
```

Comment: @muru this is not a dupe, I've gone through all the instructions everywhere and this kept failing for me. The answer is to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and stuff works.

Comment: @Juliano yeah, that doesn't make it not a dupe. If you have a different answer to the same question, just post it there.

Comment: How is an extremely specific error like this a dupe of "easiest way to run GUI apps in WSL"? The solution to this error makes absolutely no sense in there. I can't iamgine posting it there. Another point is googling for this specific error message brings up like 4 different things, o which this question is the only promissing one.